# How to allow traffic from specific countries cloudflare

Tags: python, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I can't allow traffic from specific countries using Cloudflare API.

That's a code that I tried:

```
def CountryFirewall(self, zone_id, countries):
formatted_countries = ' '.join(\[f'"{country}"' for country in countries\])
expression = f"(not ip.geoip.country in {{{formatted_countries}}})"

        url = f"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{zone_id}/firewall/rules"
        
        data = {
            "description": "Allow traffic from specific countries",
            "action": "Block",
            "filter": {
                "expression": expression,
                "paused": False
            }
        }
        response = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, json=data)
    
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.text)
            return True
        else:
            print(response.text)
            return False

countries = \['RU'\]

clf.CountryFirewall('zoneID', countries)
```

But I got this error:

> {   "result": null,   "success": false,   "errors": [     {       "code": 10014,       "message": "firewallrules.api.malformed_request_body"     }   ],   "messages": [] }

Comment: Why don't you just use `countries = ['RU']`?